# How does Module change the scope?

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

#### My understanding of scope

I have been a Javascript developer for a long time and I am used to this...

```js
var globalVar = "some value";

getGlobalVar = function(){
  alert(globalVar);
}
getGlobalVar();
```

In Javascript everything defined outside of a function is attached to the window object and becomes part of the global scope. Anything that is part of the global scope is accessible within any function - at least as far as I'm aware. I am trying to do something similar in Ruby, but I am getting an error.

#### The problem

Here is how I have the code working:

```
# create CoreController
SINATRA = Sinatra
module Apollo
  class Sinatra < SINATRA::Base
    configure :development do
      register SINATRA::Reloader
      also_reload "app/**/*.rb"
      dont_reload "lib/**/*.rb"
    end

    include CoreHelpers
    include Helpers

    # ----- Config ------
    configure do
      set :public_folder, Apollo.config[:sinatra][:public]
      set :views, Apollo.config[:sinatra][:views]
      set :static_cache_control, [:public, {:max_age => 600}]
      enable :sessions
      # Set the session secret
      set :session_secret, "secret"
    end
  end
end
```

I added `SINATRA = Sinatra` as a hack, because I could not access `Sinatra::Reloader` inside of `class Sinatra < SINATRA::Base`.

This is what I would like the code to look like:

```
# create CoreController
module Apollo
  class Sinatra < Sinatra::Base
    configure :development do
      register Sinatra::Reloader
      also_reload "app/**/*.rb"
      dont_reload "lib/**/*.rb"
    end

    include CoreHelpers
    include Helpers

    # ----- Config ------
    configure do
      set :public_folder, Apollo.config[:sinatra][:public]
      set :views, Apollo.config[:sinatra][:views]
      set :static_cache_control, [:public, {:max_age => 600}]
      enable :sessions
      # Set the session secret
      set :session_secret, "secret"
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

[image]

How does putting this code inside of a class change the scope? Shouldn't global variables be accessible anywhere? Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get all the technicalities right, but when you have class Sinatra and you use Sinatra::Something inside the class block, ruby interprets it as "he wants to access the constant Something in this class".
If you change the class name to something other than Sinatra, you should be fine. Or you can use the double colon as a prefix, like this

```
# create CoreController
module Apollo
  class Sinatra < ::Sinatra::Base
    configure :development do
      register ::Sinatra::Reloader
      also_reload "app/**/*.rb"
      dont_reload "lib/**/*.rb"
    end

    include CoreHelpers
    include Helpers

    # ----- Config ------
    configure do
      set :public_folder, Apollo.config[:sinatra][:public]
      set :views, Apollo.config[:sinatra][:views]
      set :static_cache_control, [:public, {:max_age => 600}]
      enable :sessions
      # Set the session secret
      set :session_secret, "secret"
    end
  end
end
```

It basically says ruby to look outside of the class Sinatra for another Sinatras.

Comment: So basically, for some reason, Ruby assumes I am looking in this class and not in the global scope. It would be nice if when I get an undefined error it would check the global scope automatically, kinda how local variables overwrite global in Javascript, but you can still access the global scope.